# why a C++ "const" function can modify its pointer-type member?

Tags: c++

I have the following codes that failed compilation due to `invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define N 3

void f(int *p) 
{
    *p=8;
}

class A
{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        void init() const;
        void print() const {cout<<a<<endl;}
};

void A::init() const
{
    f(&a);
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.init();
    a.print();
}
```

This is not surprising at all because of the "const" qualifier of the "init" function.

However, the following codes compiled and ran smoothly,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define N 3

void f(void **pp)
{
    *pp = new int[N];
}

class A
{
    private:
        int * p;
    public:
        void init() const;
        void assign() {for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++) p[i]=i;}
        void print() const {for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++) cout<<p[i]<<" "; cout<<endl; }
        ~A(){delete [] p;} 
};

void A::init() const
{
    f((void**)&p);
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.init();
    a.assign();
    a.print();
}
```

Question: in the second case, why a "const" function (init) can modify its member (p)?

Comment: don't forget to free(). also better use new or constructors won't get called. this is not C.

Comment: @v.oddou: This isn't generic code -- there's no constructor to be called here.  Freeing the memory would just make an example more complicated than necessary, i.e. no longer *minimal*.

Comment: @BenVoigt: that's right, but just saying. you'll obviously have noticed the C-ness of this code, Hailiang needs to be sensitized to moving towards C++ (iota algorithm, foreach lambda, avoid naked pointers (here a unique_ptr) use new/delete, be extra careful with C-style casts... but it is off topic.

Comment: Your `(void**)` cast is removing the 'constness' of &p. As simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, and codes refactored to C++ style now (and question still apply). Anyway, I think Michael Burr's answer is very concise and precise.

Comment: @Michael Burr. I just tried `(void*)` cast for the first case, and it still failed compilation. Why `(void*)` was not removing 'constness'?

Comment: @HailiangZhang: using a `(void*)` cast in example 1 fails because `f()` takes an `int*` argument not a `void*` argument. Try throwing in a `(int*)` cast instead.  Or a `const_cast<int*>()` to be more explicit about what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your C-style cast is doing a `const_cast` (among other things), which allows you to obtain a writable view of a non-const object even if all you had was a read-only view.

However, it can break horribly (cause undefined behavior) if you aren't careful.  Consider:

```
const A a;
int main()
{
    a.init();
    //a.assign();
    a.print();
}
```

This could fail spectacularly at runtime, if your toolchain put `a` into read-only memory.

`const` in C++, like `private`, does not provide *security*.  It is part of the type system, and leverages the compiler's type checker to help you catch coding errors.  But typing information can always be overridden with casts.

Finally, **if you don't want to accidentally cast away `const`, don't use C-style casts**.  If you used `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` the compiler would have caught the mistake.

Comment: Thanks! Can you be more specific where my C-style cast is doing a const_cast (among other things)? Please note a modification of the codes for c++-style

Comment: @HailiangZhang: C++ style would be `reinterpret_cast<void**>(&p)`, and it would warn you about the loss of `const` qualification.